# ExpansionTile Title color changes on expansion

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

```
ExpansionTile(
                title: Text('test'),
                children: [Text('test expanded')],
              ),
```

In this simple test, when I click on the title to expand the widget, the original title text turns from black to grey.

I'm not sure if this is a Theme issue (I tried changing every grey color to something bright) or is something that I can manage through `ExpansionTile` (don't see it in the hover menu).

I did find that I could explicitly state the text color should be black and then it stays constant. However, in my real world use case for this tile I have several Text widgets and don't want to have to color each one.

Any ideas on how to address this in one shot?

[image: expanded text in grey]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is an animated color between `accentColor` & `subtitle1 color`. So, you can override theme like this.

```dart
Theme(
  data: ThemeData(
    accentColor: Colors.black,
    textTheme: TextTheme(
      subtitle1: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
    ),
  ),
  child: ExpansionTile(
    title: Text('test'),
    children: [Text('test expanded')],
  ),
),
```